# Getting citations in chronological order when using elsarticle class

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle

I'm using the  elsarticle document class provided by Elsevier to submit a paper. In-text citations appear as you cite them or in alphabethical order with the 'sort' option:

> (Bob, 2018; John, 2001).

How can they become chronological without having to sort yourself? For example, from \citet{Bob2018,John2001} how to get:

> e.g. (John, 2001; Bob, 2018)

Here is a MWEB:

```
\documentclass[authoryear,review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Bob2018,
  author = {Bob, A.},
  year = {2018},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{John2001,
  author = {John, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\citet{John2001,Bob2018}

\citet{Bob2018,John2001}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! Please change the ordering of the bibliography key.

Comment: Thank you! I know this possibility, but I would like to do it automatically with some  sorting option. Like the \usepackage[sorting=ynt]{biblatex} (which doesn't work with elsearticle..

Comment: With a minimal document and standard `\cite` command I see no sorting of the citation keys, i.e. `\cite{Doe,Kent}` and `\cite{Kent,Doe}` produce different output.  Can you provide a minimal document demonstrating the problem, cf. [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: Edited question. The goal is to have a chronological sorting..

Comment: Yes I can but I am curious to know if the elsarticle class can achieve what I need.

Answer (score 2):

I used `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}`, and citations are appearing in sequence now.

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please elaborate a bit more to prevent deletion of your contribution?